# Error when using command 'make'

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, configure

I get error whenever I'm trying to 'make' file, I did this before I typed 'make':

```
tar xjf xarchiver-0.5.4.tar.bz2 
cd ./xarchiver-0.5.4 
./configure
```

Configure command:

```
thomas@thomas-pc:~/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for AIX... no
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for intltool >= 0.31... 0.37.1 found
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
(cached) (cached) checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for strcasestr... yes
checking for mkdtemp... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... yes
checking for dgettext in libc... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for msgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for dcgettext... yes
checking if msgfmt accepts -c... yes
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for catalogs to be installed...  bg ca cs da de el en_GB es eu fi fr hu id ja nb_NO nl pl pt_BR pt_PT ru sq sv tr uk
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... (cached) yes
checking for locales directory... ${datarootdir}/locale
checking for additional xgettext flags... --keyword=Q_ --from-code=UTF-8
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for pkg-config >= 0.9.0... 0.28
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10.0... not found
*** The required package gtk+-2.0 was not found on your system.
*** Please install gtk+-2.0 (atleast version 2.10.0) or adjust
*** the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
*** installed the package in a nonstandard prefix so that
*** pkg-config is able to find it.
```

Error:

```
    thomas@thomas-pc:~/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4'
Making all in icons
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons'
Making all in 16x16
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/16x16'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/16x16'
Making all in 24x24
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/24x24'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/24x24'
Making all in 48x48
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/48x48'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/48x48'
Making all in scalable
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/scalable'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/scalable'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons'
Making all in pixmaps
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/pixmaps'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/pixmaps'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/po'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/po'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/src'
Making all in xdgmime
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/src/xdgmime'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/src/xdgmime'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/src'
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I..   -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DDATADIR=\"/usr/share\" -DSRCDIR=\"..\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT xarchiver-socket.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/xarchiver-socket.Tpo" -c -o xarchiver-socket.o `test -f 'socket.c' || echo './'`socket.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/xarchiver-socket.Tpo" ".deps/xarchiver-socket.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/xarchiver-socket.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
socket.c:21:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:417: recipe for target 'xarchiver-socket.o' failed
make[3]: *** [xarchiver-socket.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/src'
Makefile:783: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/src'
Makefile:386: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4'
Makefile:279: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Output for make install command:

```
thomas@thomas-pc:~/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4$ make install
Making install in icons
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons'
Making install in 16x16
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/16x16'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/16x16'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps" || mkdir -p -- "/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/share/icons’: Permission denied
Makefile:272: recipe for target 'install-iconsDATA' failed
make[3]: *** [install-iconsDATA] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/16x16'
Makefile:335: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons/16x16'
Makefile:281: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/Downloads/xarchiver-0.5.4/icons'
Makefile:386: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Is that the complete output from the `make` command? Did the `./configure` script run successfully and create the expected Makefile(s)?

Comment: I edited the post, I added the whole output of make and configure command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `make` command is failing for the simple reason that the `./configure` script did not complete successfully, as indicated by the error messages:

```
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10.0... not found
*** The required package gtk+-2.0 was not found on your system.
*** Please install gtk+-2.0 (atleast version 2.10.0) or adjust
*** the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable` if you
*** installed the package in a nonstandard prefix so that
*** pkg-config is able to find it.
```

If you have installed `gtk+-2.0` manually (e.g. from source) then you will need to tell the configure script how/where to find it. Otherwise, you likely just need to install the `libgtk2.0-dev` package from the repository, either from the Software Center application or from the command line using `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`.

Comment: I installed libgtk2.0-dev. I did make, but when I typed make install there is another error I added in the post

Comment: Those are `Permission denied` errors: since the software is trying to install in `/usr/local` where you need root permissions (`sudo make install`). **You might want to look at the option of using [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) in place of install**

Comment: Hi. Thx for post, but I installed that libgtk2.0-dev package, but still I have all-recursive] error when compile by 'make' (editing litecoin source)